# How can I change the footer of an unnumbered chapter inserted after a numbered chapter or an appendix?

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, chapters, fancyhdr, starred-version

Thank you all for your time, I just began to use LaTeX and this website so forgive me if my question has already been made, but I've searched a bit and didn't found anything that works for my situation.

I'm using Sharelatex and my document class is a two-sided report. To manage the headers and the footers of my thesis I'm using the fancyhdr package; it's code in my preamble looks like this:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{Title of the thesis}
\setlength{\headheight}{14.49998pt}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[CO,CE]{Chapter \thechapter}
\fancyfoot[LO,RE]{Edoardo Serra}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
```

To insert an unnumbered chapter, and in order for it to figure out in the Table of Contents, I use the following code:

```
\chapter*{Introduction}
\input{chapters/introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}
```

The problem arises when I want to insert an unnumbered chaper after a numbered one or after an appendix, because the footer of the unnumbered chaper given by the string of code `\fancyfoot[CO,CE]{Chapter \thechapter}` remains the one of the numbered chapter or appendix above.
How can I, if possible, insert there the name of the unnumbered chapter instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can redefine `\chaptermark` and use `\leftmark` for the footer. Then you can set the footer entry for the unnumbered chapter manually.

Example:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength{\headheight}{14.49998pt}
\renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{\markboth{\chaptername~\thechapter}{}}

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{Title of the thesis}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[CO,CE]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyfoot[LO,RE]{Edoardo Serra}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\blinddocument

\chapter*{Introduction}
  \markboth{Introduction}{}% right after chapter title
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}% right after chapter title!
\Blindtext

\blinddocument\blinddocument\blinddocument\blinddocument
\end{document}
```